# How to get the download file path on linux?

Tags: java, linux, hibernate, spring-mvc, download

I have finished developing a java web app using spring and hibernate. In my app, there's a download function. The function runs well on windows env. But when I deploy and run the app on linux env, using Tomcat as the server, the function return zero byte file. The file type is excel (xls). But the browser returns this as pdf file.

Download Function Failed:

[image: Download Failed]

Xls File Path on Linux:
[image: xls]

and here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping("downloadXlsTemplate")
public String downloadTemplate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {           

        String filename = "Template.xls";

        File onLinux  = new File("/opt/tomcat7/webapps/xls/" + filename); 

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        response.setContentLength((int) onLinux.length());

        InputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream(onLinux);

        OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bytes;
        while((bytes = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        responseOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return null;
}
```

I have tried various ways, but none were successful.
I will really appreciate any idea, help, or solution

Regards
Yunus

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is a file permission problem. The file is owned by 'root' and your tomcat runs on other user.

Try to move the files to a shared location where the tomcat user can access it. Try the `/tmp` location or any other shared location.

Answer (score 0):

If it is permission issue, try using chmod unix command giving required permission on file .

e.g., chmod u+rwx

As a good practice, try to refer the file using relative path (using class path resource) instead of absolute path (so it is environment independent).